# NameError: name 'anekdot' is not defined. Did you mean: 'anekdots'?

Tags: python

Good afternoon, trying to output a random list item from this code

```
global anekdot

def randanek():

    anekdot = random.choice(anekdots)


randanek()
textaneka = anekdot
```

but for some reason the program doesn't see my variable and i see this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 44, in <module>
    textaneka = anekdot
NameError: name 'anekdot' is not defined. Did you mean: 'anekdots'?
[Finished in 113ms with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '']]
[dir: /]
[path: /]
```

i try to use different variable

Comment: In what way(s) did you "try to use different variable"?

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'anekdots' is not defined`.

Comment: You must set anekdot as global INSIDE your function for it to modify the outer var (and actually define it before the function). But yes, better use "return".

Comment: Learn how to use return values from functions. `global` will only cause you pain as you learn

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is of how python is interpreting your code. You say you want anekdot to be a global, but don't give it a value. You think the compiler will figure out that anekdot is assigned a value within the function, but it is hitting an error before that because it sees `texaneka = anekdot` and doesn't know what `anekdot` is.

In python, it's usually better to do this with function returns.

```
def randanek():
  return random.choice(anekdots)

textaneka = randanek()
```

In this example, you don't need to bother with the variable `anekdot` at all, and your code is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write something like this:

```py
anekdots = [
    "anekdot 1 blah blah blah",
    "anekdot 2 blah blah blah",
    # etc
]


def randanek():
    return random.choice(anekdots)


textaneka = randanek()
```

Have a read some info about how functions work
https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/